# Как происходит компиляция исходного текста С++ с помощью gcc?

Tags: c++, unix, компиляция, ncurses, линковка

Доброго времени суток.

Предыстория такая: изучаю С++ по книге Лафоре, и там очень много примеров используют библиотеку conio.h. Насколько я понял, эта библиотека не является стандартной. Где-то прочитал, что лучшим аналогом является библиотека ncurses.h. Долгими тыканиями-мыканиями и непонятными заклинаниями мне удалось "сварить" исполняемый файл, но я так толком не понял что происходит, а печатать непонятные заклинания в консоль мне не нравится.
Разъясните, пожалуйста, на человеческом языке, что происходит, когда ввожу в консоль что-нибудь вроде:

```
g++ someSource.cpp
```

Что сработает сначала: препроцессор или линкер? Как указать линкеру на собственную папку с библиотеками (где-нибудь в домашней папке, напрмер)? Где, например, прописывается для gcc, куда скидывать скомпилированные файлы? В общем, что происходит, когда я прошу систему скомпилировать исходник?

Answer (score 4):

Разумеется, линкер работает последним, поскольку он собирает из объектников исполняемый файл. Объектники ему поставляет компилятор. А перед компиляцией проходит препроцессор, подставляя макросы и т.п.

Касательно опций и настроек gcc и иже с ним - читайте их документацию.